# How can I disable autostart of mysql server?

Tags: server, mysql, autostart

I'm using Ubuntu Xenial and mysql 5.
editing the mysql.conf file didn't help. it's still showing active.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd to control autostart of services. Try using the systemctl command:

```
sudo systemctl disable mysql
```

Comment: Tried that on Ubuntu 17.10 several times .. but mysql starts on every boot. 
--- - - log ---- -  - 
mysql.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable mysql

Comment: I confirm this work in Ubuntu **18.04** too